# Babylon.js - models created with Blender appear rounded and weirdly shaped

Tags: blender, babylonjs

I am working on a Babylon.js project. Therefore I created a test model (.babylon) with Blender (the export worked perfectly without any errors).

My Problem is: The model in my browser [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL7cE.jpg) (Babylon.js) looks somewhat different than the model in Blender [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQToI.jpg).

Model in babylon

[image]

Model in blender

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQToI.jpg]

To import the mesh to my Babylon scene, i am using `BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh`.

Babylon.js seems to somehow round the edged, which I really don't understand - there are plenty of examples of perfect models! I know I am doing sth. terribly wrong, but I just can't figure out what it is... So far I tried things like using older Blender Versions, reinstalling the export-python-script and googling like a lunatic. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? (I did not add any modifiers to the mesh in Blender)

**TL;DR**: models in Babylon.js look weird (sharp edges are somehow round) - using .babylon file created with Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the surface normals are being averaged, so that the shader interpolates the individual polygons and makes the shape look smoother. I am not sure whether it is the Blender export or the Babylonjs material that's causing it. The actual geometry is the same though, if you compare the silhouettes. Keep in mind that it's often desirable to have this effect, especially for organic models.
In case you are not familiar with normals, have a look at http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/introduction-to-shading/shading-normals which probably explains it better.

If you want to retain flat shaded look from blender, try doing some like:
`monkey_shape.convertToFlatShadedMesh()`

Comment: Thank you so much, that method was exactly what I was looking for! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set flat shading directly in blender, for the entire scene (see picture) or for individual meshes (data properties of the mesh in blender).

[image]