# Babylon js not all smooth polygons

Tags: blender, smoothing, 3d-modelling, babylonjs

I have some problem. I work with babylon js and blender. In blender i have model with smoothed polygons, but when I am export model to babylon, than some polygons do not looks smoothed. On hood and neck.

[screen from blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Mum.jpg)

[screen from babylon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU7xN.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527372/babylon-js-models-created-with-blender-appear-rounded-and-weirdly-shaped/37532979#37532979? Maybe it's related...

Comment: Yes, I looked. This not exactly what i need. My problem on the contrary and my problem dont decide that way.

Comment: Maybe bringing this question to Babylon forum could give you more answers